# Android customizable calendar

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I started working with `CalendarView` today, and to my surprise, class is very inflexible.

Only methods that `CalendarView` allos me to override are:

- getDate()
- getFirstDayOfWeek()
- getMaxDate()
- getMinDate()
- getShowWeekNumber()
- isEnabled()
- setDate(long, boolean, boolean)
- setDate(long)
- setEnabled(boolean)
- setFirstDayOfWeek(int)
- setMaxDate(long)
- setMinDate(long)
- setOnDateChangeListener(OnDateChangeListener)
- setShowWeekNumber(boolean)

However, i need to customize how certain days are displayed. For example, in my database i have events for dates 2013-10-02 and 2013-12-02 and i want to highlight these days in my calendar. How would i go about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own CustomCalenderView.
Extends the Native CalendarView and build the behaviour that you want to color the background.
Or you can use this library : TimesSquare for Android.

And think it provide what you are looking for .